# Laravel 5.4 csrf_field() not working

Tags: php, laravel-5.4, csrf-protection

I am trying to make a simple view and I want to be able to make a post request. I need to generate a csrf token and this is the html view that I have:

```
<form method="POST" action="/formsubmit">
{!! csrf_field() !!}
First Name: <br>
<input type="text" name="firstname"><br>
Last Name:<br>s
<input type="text" name="lastname"><br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit"><br>   
</form>
```

This is my route:

```
Route::get('form', function(){
return view('form');
});

Route::post('formsubmit',function(){
return 'Form Posted.';
});
Auth::routes();
```

This is what  happens when I try the url:

[image]

As you can see, it just prints the name of the function, but the function is not ever called and the hidden field is not being generated. Is there something that needs to be done in order to make it work?

Comment: Is the form's view template located at `resources/views/form.php` or `resources/views/form.blade.php`?

Comment: it's in resources/views/form.blade.php

Comment: Oh my goodness no it was resources/views/form.php. I changed it to resources/views/form.blade.php and it worked!  arrgh Thanks.. It was in front of me the whole time.. it's my first time using Laravel, I need to get used to seeing these things.

Comment: Glad I could help. I've added an answer below. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Blade's templating language will only get interpreted in a file with a `.blade.php` extension. One with just a `.php` extension will work with Laravel, but you won't have any Blade functionality.

Comment: Very good point to note. I had forgot to add `.blade.php`. in the file name.